lambda calls consume less memory than regular function calls? (stack overflow difference on lambda vs regular function)
with regular function:
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using std::cout;

//timer
using A = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using B = std::chrono::duration<double,std::ratio<1>>;
using C = std::chrono::time_point<A>;
C timer{A::now()};
double elap(C x){return std::chrono::duration_cast<B>(A::now()-timer).count();}

//counter
int count{0};

//recursive function
void repeat() {
    cout<<++count<<" - "<<elap(timer)<<'s'<<'\n';
    repeat();
    cout<<"test";
}

int main() {repeat();}


this prints till there's an overflow, the last line I get is "174372 - 1.00188s"
with a lambda:
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
using std::cout;

//timer
using A = std::chrono::steady_clock;
using B = std::chrono::duration<double,std::ratio<1>>;
using C = std::chrono::time_point<A>;
C timer{A::now()};
double elap(C x){return std::chrono::duration_cast<B>(A::now()-timer).count();}

//counter
int count{0};

int main() {

    //lambda definition
    auto repeat=[](this auto repeat) -> void {
        cout<<++count<<" - "<<elap(timer)<<'s'<<'\n';
        repeat();
        cout<<"test";
    };
    repeat();

}


this prints till there's an overflow, the last line I get is "1220751 - 7.18137s".
on the line 174372 (where the regular function stop printing) I get the following: "174372 - 0.988323s"
There's not a huge different in speed, but a big one on how much longer the recursive lambda call lasted compared to the regular recursive one. I suppose the lambda calls allocate less memory, what would be the reason for such behavior?


Tried to call two equivalent recurse functions (a lambda and a regular one), I got different results.
Compiler: gcc 14.2.1
Flags: -std=c++23 -O2 -DNDEBUG`
OS: Arch Linux (kernel 6.12.1)
CPU: Intel i5-1135G7
link to godbolt (regular function): https://godbolt.org/z/azsxoaMxE
link to godbolt (lambda): https://godbolt.org/z/WajW3PhWP

How do you compile? Have you enabled optimizations?

The behaviour of both functions might differ with compiler optimizations (-O2, -O3, etc.). To understand the exact cause, inspect the assembly or intermediate representation generated by the compiler.
The stack size and behaviour of recursion can vary between operating systems, compilers, and runtime environments.

Whenever asking a question like "why does this code, whose behavior is formally undefined, behave as it does", you need to state your compiler, compilation options, CPU architecture, and operating system. Such questions can usually only be answered by being able to reproduce the behavior - occasionally someone will know a general answer off the top of their head, but it's not the norm.

If you can demonstrate it on https://godbolt.org/, and include a share link, that's a plus.

Why would you ever try to use time as a proxy for space? Just count the levels of recursion if that's what you care about, or log the address of a local variable directly to see how it changes

Minor point: << 's' << '\n' can be written << "s\n".

I add the compiler, flags, OS, CPU and godbolt links to the post now, thanks. For now I don't know how to read the assembly  the compiler does, but soon will pick to learn it.

@PeteBecker I had missed the first snippet.

Looking at the assembly at the godbolt link, the lambda got unrolled - turned into something like for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {std::cout <<++count...}; repeat(); for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {std::cout <<"test"}. The regular function call is not similarly unrolled. Why, I don't know.
